# Specified cast is not valid on listview item c#

Tags: c#, listview, casting, xamarin.forms, selecteditemchanged

I basically have a listview, with this function when i click on a listview-item.

When i run this and click on the item, i get the following display alerts before my app crashes.

DisplayAlert 1, then DisplayAlert 2, then DisplayAlert 1 and right after this one my app crashes. With "Specified cast is not valid".

I dont know why i get the DisplayAlert 1 again, and why this crashes.

```
public async void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("1", "1", "1");
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return; // ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
        }

        //((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

        await DisplayAlert("2", "2", "2");
        // Cast to zoneviewmodel type
        var selectedZone = (ViewModel.ZoneViewModel)e.SelectedItem; 


        await DisplayAlert("3", "3", "3");
        // Redirect to login
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage(selectedZone.Address));

        await DisplayAlert("4", "4", "4");
        // send message containing information to fill loginpage information
        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, ViewModel.ZoneViewModel>(this, "loginInfo", selectedZone);
    }
```

Comment: what is the exception message you get? and it seems your OnSelection event is firing two times

Comment: What do type of object do you put in your list?

Comment: Unhandled Exception:System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. occurred @Eddy

Comment: Ah ok @JazzW, then this line is causing the exception: `var selectedZone = (ViewModel.ZoneViewModel)e.SelectedItem; ` SelectedItem is not of type ZoneViewModel... Try to debug and see the exact type of SelectedItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line: `var selectedZone = (ViewModel.ZoneViewModel)e.SelectedItem;` you're trying to cast whatever is in your list to `ViewModel.ZoneViewModel`. The error is telling you this list item is not assignable to this type. If you're not sure what type the item is, step through or print out `e.SelectedItem.GetType()`.

Comment: I have edited and added a printscreen, from the ViewModel.ZoneViewModel.cs. My list is an ObserableCollection : /// 
        private static ObservableCollection<ViewModel.ZoneViewModel> Zones;

Comment: @JazzW You'll need to set a breakpoint on that line to see what exactly `SelectedItem` is.